# Is it Possible to take existing Python Script file and run it on the web

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take existing python code and run it as a web application. I am not entirely sure on how to do this, I was thinking about connecting the code to flask or django, but have no idea where to start.

Comment: You need to implement a web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Amrit, what you are asking is possible, but you should consider reading the documentations of both flask and django, aswell as doing some research to try to understand which would serve you better. You will learn a lot from chasing those answers on your own.

If you want to start with django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

If you want to start with flask:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Comment: Hi Daniel, I was actually looking at django and installed the environment, and even watched a couple of tutorials. But, I was still lost on how to take my existing file and simple use it with django. A lot of these tutorials only show how to make a new web application from scratch, nothing about using existing code. Sorry if I sound kinda dumb, new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @AmritSingh, don't worry. At start things are a bit complicated. But basicaly, when someone teaches the process of making things from scratch, you should really pay attention to the structure you need to build for an specific end. After that, using your own functions and files replicating (and even adapting) that structure should be easy.